# django api with custom user app authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-registration

I created a django project tha uses a customUser for authentication, following [this](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model) blog post.

I now would like to attach another app to the project that is a REST API that leverages that authentication.

In this new app I create a model for the data that the uses will consume and I add as foreign key in the model the custom user model previously created.

```
#project/api/models.py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

from accounts.models import CustomUser


class Signal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    data = ArrayField(models.FloatField(), unique=True)
    threshold = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"
```

while the `project/api/views.py` file is

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import pluralize
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.response import Response

from . import serializers
from .algorithm.compute_crossing import count_crossing_pos as count_cross
from .models import Signal


class SignalViewset(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Signal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SignalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)


class SignalDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Signal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SignalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)


@api_view(http_method_names=["POST"])
def send_data(request: Request) -> Response():
    """send signal data with threshold in request payload
    and compute crossing times around given threshold
    :param request: [request payload]
    :type request: [type]
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        count = count_cross(request.data.get("data"), request.data.get("threshold"))
        return Response(
            {
                "status": "success",
                "info": "signal crosses the given threshold {} tim{}".format(
                    count, pluralize(count, "e,es")
                ),
                "count": str(count),
            },
            status=200,
        )
    else:
        count = count_cross(request.data.get("data"), request.data.get("threshold"))
        return Response(
            {
                "status": "success",
                "info": "you are an  AnonymousUser but I will give you an answer nonetheless \n \n signal crosses the given threshold {} tim{}".format(
                    count, pluralize(count, "e,es")
                ),
                "count": str(count),
            },
            status=200,
        )
```

Everytime I access the `send_data` endpoint I go into the else statement as `request.user.is_authenticated` is False.
how do I connect the rest api with the authentication (accounts) app?

my `settings.py` file is:

```
from pathlib import Path

from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

SYSTEM_ENV = config("SYSTEM_ENV")
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "*",
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "api",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "dj_rest_auth",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "dj_rest_auth.registration",
    "accounts",
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"  # new
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "signal_crossing.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("templates"))],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "signal_crossing.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases


if SYSTEM_ENV == "PRODUCTION" or SYSTEM_ENV == "STAGING":
    print("docker")
    DEBUG = False
    SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY")
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
            "NAME": "postgres",
            "USER": "postgres",
            "PASSWORD": "postgres",
            "HOST": "db",
            "PORT": 5432,
        }
    }


elif SYSTEM_ENV == "GITHUB_WORKFLOW":
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = "TESTING_KEY"
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
            "NAME": "github_actions",
            "USER": "postgres",
            "PASSWORD": "postgres",
            "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
            "PORT": "5432",
        }
    }


elif SYSTEM_ENV == "DEVELOPMENT":
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = "DEVELOP_KEY"
    # DATABASES = {
    #     "default": {
    #         "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
    #         "NAME": config("DB_NAME"),
    #         "USER": config("POSTGRES_LOCAL_USER"),
    #         "PASSWORD": config("POSTGRES_LOCAL_PASSWORD"),
    #         "HOST": "localhost",
    #         "PORT": "5432",
    #     }
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
        }
    }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
SITE_ID = 1


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        "dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication",
    ],
}

REST_USE_JWT = True
JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = "my-app-auth"


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # allauth specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of allauth
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
]
# ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username"
# LOGIN_URL = "/login/"
# LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
# LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "signal_crossing.settings"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
```

Comment: Please share your settings.py file?

Comment: How are you testing your API? Did you authenticate using JWT and are you passing the authentication token in the request header?

Comment: that;s the point actually. I login using the customUser that is not returning any JWT.

Comment: What is your log in process? And once logged in, how do you POST to your send_data endpoint? Postman?